User-specific search results, based on purchase history, combined with result filtering
I have an index (products) of all our available products. These products all have unique groups of attributes (like, size, or color, etc).
I want to allow my users to search through their purchase history, finding all the products they've previously purchased, and allow them to utilize the product attributes to filter those results.
My product count is 20k and growing at about 10k-20k per year.
How should I structure my index to facilitate this type of search query?
Adding an index with records for every userID_productID for everything they've ever purchased seems unscalable, cost-wise, as my users purchase several thousand of my products, each, which scales my record count into the 10s of millions.
I think the number of buyers for any given product will exceed the allowed size of the record, if I add all the purchasing user ids to an attribute on the product.
I also think that pushing up the list of purchased products to the API for the query would be too large as well (think select * from product where <filter requirements> and product_id in (<list of all product ids user has ever purchased>).
How do I connect these two queries?

I think you should maintain a different DB with the purchases records (SQL, redis or anything really).
Could be a simple as: user_id, object_id, date_time
Then when querying Algolia, you can filter by objectID to search within the records that your user bought. This approach can be also used for favorites or any other form of wishlist feature.

this would be my preferred way, but as I understand it, an algolia query can only be 10k, and with 64bit product IDs, you can "only" send 1250 of them or so at a time. you really need to query the whole corpus in order to sort and paginate the results correctly :/ I'm probably going to have to use a db focused solution, which kinda sucks since it means duplicating a lot of work that algolia does really well :/

curious where you found that 1250 number ? as the search request body size is 50MB

I saw somewhere on their docs where it sounded like it was 10k. 50mb sounds a lot more workable!

do you happen to know if/where that's documented?

Is is here under "Search request body size"
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/scaling/algolia-service-limits/

thanks a ton, this will save a ton of time
